# Extending a line bundle from a subvariety to the union

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

If I have a smooth projective variety $X$, where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are subvarieties, where they have same codimension in $X$. If I have a line bundle $L$ on $Y_1$, and non-zero rational section $f_{Y_1}$. Is it possible to extend L the line bundle $L$ to $L' \rightarrow Y_1 \cup Y_2$ and $f_{Y_1}$ to $g_{Y_1 \cup Y_2}$, so that $div(f)_{Y_1} = div(g)_{Y_1 \cup Y_2}$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It is also a bad idea to post the same question on MO at the same time.